# Uninstal the nginx configured with RTMP - ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I configured the nginx according to the [vultr](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-nginx-rtmp-on-ubuntu-14-04) , Then i had to remove it , so i removed it using `sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx` and after that `sudo apt-get autoremove` . No error till now . But now when i need to install nginx again using [Digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) tutorial it's installed but at the time of start  I keeps me giving error like below

```
root@onebyteRails:~/working/nginx-1.7.5# sudo update-rc.d nginx
defaults  System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/nginx already exist.
root@onebyteRails:~/working/nginx-1.7.5# sudo service nginx restart  *
Stopping Nginx Server...                                              
[fail]   * Starting Nginx Server...                                   
nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the events{} block in your nginx.conf. Here is a full working example of an nginx.conf file: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full

Answer (score 0):

[Vultr](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-nginx-rtmp-on-ubuntu-14-04) installation didn't use apt, so it was not uninstalled with `sudo apt-get autoremove`, neither the `/etc/init.d/nginx` file was removed.

To remove the `/etc/init.d/nginx`:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo update-rc.d nginx remove
sudo rm /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo rm `which nginx`
```

Nginx doesn't have a `make uninstall` option, and I don't know exactly where vultr files were placed, but the Digital Ocean install (which uses apt) will probably ask to overwrite the configuration files if they are in the same location.

If you  want to make sure you have removed all vultr nginx files before installing Digital Ocean, try running the `make install` again on the vultr src and manually removing all files it listed as updated.